# Rails one-to-one assocation on the same model with same field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I establish a one-to-one relationship between two instances of the same model so that I can identify each via the same field name?

I'm learning Rails by building a personal finance application. Transactions have LineItems. A simple transfer is recorded by creating two transactions, each having one line item. Each line item references the other. A LineItem will only ever have one, or nil, associated LineItems.

(Note: I'm handling transfers at the LineItem level because there are complex Transfers where a Transaction has multiple LineItems, of which one or more can be transfers, each to separate single LineItem Transactions).

Currently I have:

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :transfer_main, class_name: 'LineItem', optional: true
has_one :transfer_sub, class_name: 'LineItem', foreign_key: 'transfer_main_id'
...
```

```
Schema:
create_table "line_items"
...
t.integer "transfer_main_id"
...
```

Resulting in the console output:

```
#<LineItem...
id: 31,
line_amount: 100,
transfer_main_id: nil
...
#<LineItem...
id: 32,
line_amount: -100,
transfer_main_id: 31

>LineItem.find(31).transfer_sub
=>#<LineItem...
id:32
...
```

While it works okay, my logic has to check for "transfer_main_id" or "transfer_sub_id" and I'd like to just check for "transfer_id".

Something like

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
one_to_one :transfer, class_name: 'LineItem', optional: true, foreign_key: 'id'
```

Once created, transfer LineItems are of equal status, and a user could change fields of either independently and expect the "sibling" to automatically adjust. So "main" and "sub" don't make sense. What I could find about one-to-one associations involve an obvious top-down hierarchy, which isn't the case here.

This is the YNAB transaction SDK, it shows a Transaction has a field "transfer_transaction_id", so I figure it can be done in Rails, too.
https://github.com/ynab/ynab-sdk-ruby/blob/master/docs/TransactionDetail.md

Comment: "While it works okay, my logic has to check for 'transfer_main_id' or 'transfer_sub_id'" - this isn't actually true. No "transfer_sub_id" column is used.

Comment: My mistake, I would be checking for 'transfer_sub' (no '_id'), which I just double checked does work.